# What happened to Eclipse Markdown editor in 2022-06?

Tags: eclipse, markdown

On Windows 10 I always install Eclipse by downloading and unzipping the Java EE version. The EE version has long had a Markdown editor for `*.md` files. Although it was a very limited editor, at least it gave me a brief preview and provided a some styling in the source editor (although it didn't understand the any complex subtleties of Markdown).

I just installed `eclipse-jee-2022-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip` for Eclipse 2022-06, and I when I clicked on a `readme.md` file it suddenly opened the file an external editor instead of opening it inside Eclipse.

OK, so maybe they decided that the built-in Markdown editor was too crummy to keep using. But the other problem is that the Markdown file type icon doesn't seem to have transparency correctly set. It shows a text document, but the background is black, which looks ugly (and startling) beside the other file icons.

What happened to Eclipse Markdown editor in 2022-06 and why is the Markdown icon messed up?

Comment: The [Markdown editor has been removed from the JEE IDE package by mistake](https://twitter.com/akurtakov/status/1538422404526903296). Eclipse is open source. It would be nice if you would give feedback to Eclipse based on the milestones before the release to avoid such things in the future. If you have the skills, you might consider to contribute to the Eclipse Mylyn Docs Wikitext project that provides the Markdown editor to eliminate the limitations you are facing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*As mentioned in the various comments the editor was removed from the stuff included by default in the JEE package by mistake (by me ) Sorry for the inconvenience. Here is the step-by-step to add it to the 2022-06 release.*

1. From the *Help* menu -> *Install New Software...*

[image: help menu screenshot]

2. In the *Available Software* UI's *Work with* combo box, choose `--All Available Sites--` (*You can also choose specifically `2022-06 - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06/`*)

[image: choose all available sites]

3. Type `wikitext` in the filter box. The name is wikitext because that is the feature that contains editing support for many markup languages.

[image: wikitext typed into filter box]

4. Check `Mylyn WikiText` and complete the wizard

[image: wikitext selected]

5. Resume normal service editing Markdown files

[image: screenshot of eclipse]

Comment: 1) So are you saying that the Markdown editor will come back in future versions of Eclipse? 2) What problems will it cause if I manually add it back now and then it appears in later versions of Eclipse? 3) Why is the existing Markdown icon messed up, with a black background instead of a transparent background?

Comment: It will be included by default in the download again from 2022-09. The zip you download is an automated process that installs all items from the release repository (https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06/ in this case). There should be no problems for the next release.

Comment: As for the icon, that sounds like a bug and needs to be reported as such to the Mylyn Wikitext project - here is a link to start that process (I don't work on that project) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mylyn%20Docs&short_desc=Mylyn%20Wikitext%20icon%20for%20markdown%20has%20non-transparent%20background&component=Wikitext&cc=jonah@kichwacoders.com

Comment: To restate a different way - it was never removed from the Eclipse release, it just stopped being included by default.

Comment: Thank you. This not only brought back Markdown preview and editing, it also fixed the icon problem. By "fixed" I mean it shows a different icon with a transparent icon. Thus I would guess that the default icon that was used for Markdown in Eclipse is somehow messed up with a non-transparent background, and that the icon in the wikitext package replaces that one.

Comment: Glad you are back up and running - sorry again for the inconvenience.

Comment: But now two errors are showing up in the error log: `Unable to resolve plug-in "org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui".` and `Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/icons/eview16/task-list.png`. Could you check and make sure Mylyn was removed cleanly?

Comment: I assume in this case you are using the same workspace and there was some Mylyn view (probably tasks UI). The errors are a bit heavy weight and it would be nice if they didn't show so starkly in the case of starting an IDE with views that no longer have the code behind them. I see those errors when I have the view opened, but once I close the view the errors are gone. This is what I mean (see tasks view in the top right) https://i.imgur.com/6qdGpm1.png and https://i.imgur.com/o8dwxiG.png

Comment: Getting the Eclipse Platform to improve when this condition happen would be nice, please help by filing a but report with the maintainers of the Eclipse Platform in github: https://github.com/eclipse-platform

Comment: But Jonah I have to option to close the "Task List". The context menu just shows "Detach". Ah, after I minimized the view to the side, the new context menu had an option to close it. A bit confusing and inconsistent.

Comment: Wikitext has a bug for tables viewer :(

Comment: @JRichardsz please submit a bug report https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn.docs/issues

Answer (score 0):

That editor comes from the Mylyn Wikitext project. Mylyn was removed from the 2022-06 simultaneous release and most of the packages. You might be able to install it from http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest , but ymmv.

Comment: [_Eclipse Mylyn Docs_ is still part of the Eclipse IDE 2022-06 release](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06). I guess [it was accidentally removed with the removal of Mylyn](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/commit/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product/epp.product?id=711cdb499d09bd3cdcc5c1c722872f84fa6ffbd0). The [Java IDE package still has Wikitext](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product#n226).

Comment: According to [this commit message](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/commit/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product?id=28df848a4e1dee6c4499c6698cd2a2f0e067d0be), Mylyn task/context has been missed to be removed from the JEE IDE 2020, and then in the last release it was accidentally removed too much.